# How to configure dbox mail storage format for a single mail account?

Tags: email, postfix, webserver, ldap, dovecot

I'm using `ldap` database at backend and I want to configure my mail server such a way that one mail id i.e. `info@domain.au` will be stored as `dbox` format while other mails will be stored in `maildir` format.

I've already referred to [dovecot's official site](http://wiki2.dovecot.org/MailboxFormat/dbox) but it's too complicated for me.      Please help me on this.